# Knockout.js - cannot remove mapped object from observable array

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I've been using knockout for a while in a new app, but until recently i was manually creating objects to map complex objects (and their nested children). I then learned of the mapping plugin, and started using that. I can map objects, and add computed observables etc with no problems, however i can't remove them from the observable array when i pass it back from the UI. The remove iterates over the array, but never finds the (unedited) object to remove. Likewise I was unable to get a return of true using the == and === comparisons with the returned object and specifying the [0] location of the array containing only one object. I presume this is what is causing it not to remove, even though i think it should be exactly the same?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var viewModel = new appViewModel();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/api/Players",
    }).done(function (data) {
        viewModel.playersCollection(ko.mapping.fromJS(data));
    }).error(function (ex) {
        console.log("error retrieving players");
    });

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);    
});
```

Viewmodel

```
var appViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    this.playersCollection = ko.observableArray();

    this.confirmDeletePlayer = function (currentData) {
        self.playersCollection.remove(currentData);
    };
};
```

UI

```
<div data-bind="foreach: playersCollection()">
    <div>
        <span data-bind="text:Player.FirstName"></span>
        <span data-bind="click: $root.confirmDeletePlayer">
           <img src="delete-icon.png" />
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Please post a sample of the data that `/api/Players` returns.

Comment: See my comment below, the issue was both that i wasnt calling the mapping correctly and that my applybinding call was being made before the ajax callback had completed to populate observable data (though this part wasn't included in my snippet)

Comment: In fact you can apply bindings any time you like.  When observables change afterwards, like when an Ajax request comes in and is mapped, then your bound view will update accordingly. That's the whole point after all. If your view does not do this. you are still doing something wrong.

Comment: I'm not explaining very well what i mean. I have an observable (not array) which maps to a server side object with many properties. If i try access these properties in the view before the data is returned, i'll get a JS error as the property doesn't exist yet at rendering time. This doesnt happen with observablearrays as the foreach just wont run with no objects. My options are to either declare all of the individual properties in a new object so the view is aware of all relevant properties(which i dont want to do, its the reason i'm using Mapping) or bind after the call is complete.

Comment: I see what you mean. The clean way out is indeed to declare all the properties you want to use in your view up-front. This will make your set-up more stabe and predictable as well as a lot easier to debug. Vital internal structure like the contract between your view and your viewmodel shouldn't be hidden or dependent on ephemeral information like the contents of Ajax requests. I know the mapping plugin feels like you don't need to actually set up that contract anymore in your code, but that's a mistake if you ask me.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code from:

```
viewModel.playersCollection(ko.mapping.fromJS(data));
```

To:

```
viewModel.playersCollection = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
```

Or:

```
viewModel.playersCollection(data);
```

`playersCollection` is already an observable array, so when you call the mapping plugin, it turns `data` into an observable array. So you're adding an observable array to an observable array. I think that's causing some weird issues.

See: http://plnkr.co/edit/sYwSq3DEwf2sDSQj5s5B?p=preview

Comment: This seems to work perfectly for local arrays, but doesnt work at all after the ajax object comes back. Even creating a local version of the array and then comparing it with the ajax version returns false. I'm not sure whats going on here...

Comment: Just to clarify, the remove and binding works correctly using your above convention for a local array, but binding to the ajax call with mapping is not working at all.

Comment: Seems to work for me. Try this version: http://plnkr.co/edit/WyHGsxTwDfUchgebtorm?p=preview

Comment: It turns out i was looking in the wrong place for what wasn't working. Your answer was correct and i wasnt mapping using the right convention, but there was actually an issue further up the chain. I was able to iterate through my ajax result and push mapped objects into the array with no problem, but couldnt create nested standalone observables in other parts. It turns out that I shouldnt be doing my KO applybinding outside of the AJAX call, and the empty observables (pre .success callback) is why things failed. With your answer i was able to determine where the issue was, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do:

```
// request data as soon as possible, independent of document readiness
var playersReqest = $.get("/api/Players").fail(function (ex) {
    console.log("error retrieving players");
});

$(function () {
    // bind the vievmodel as soon as the view is ready
    var game = new GameViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(game);    

    // as soon as the data is ready, map it into the viewmodel
    playersReqest.done(function (data) {
        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, game.players);
    });
});    

function GameViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.players = ko.observableArray();

    self.deletePlayer = function (player) {
        self.players.remove(player);
    };
}
```

And

```html
<div data-bind="foreach: players">
    <div>
        <span data-bind="text: FirstName"></span>
        <span data-bind="click: $root.deletePlayer">
           <img src="delete-icon.png" />
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notes

- Bindings do not require manual unwrapping of the value. `foreach: players` is sufficient, `foreach: players()` is unnecessary.
- `foreach: players` sets the context to each player object, so inside it is likely `text: FirstName`, not `text: Player.FirstName` (or you have an unclean model mapping).
- Splitting Ajax request, model binding and data mapping into independent operations ensures that every step can happen as soon as it is ready.